# Adding '-' into string in dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe with dates in it, but the way the dates come formatted is `YYYYMMDD`, without any divider.

I tried using a line like this:

```
df['date'] = [(x[:4] + '-' + x[4:6] + '-' + x[6]) for x in df['date']]
```

but I keep getting `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

From what I've found out, that's because I'm trying to do the operation on a series in a dataframe. However, I can't seem to find another way to add in any kind of separator between the parts of the date. 
(Using `time.striptime` just gave me another error because of the lack of separator)

Is there another way to turn `YYYYMMDD` into `YYYY-MM-DD` as well as into a datetime object on an entire series in a dataframe?

EDIT:

Solved by converting the dates from a `numpy.float64` into `string` using

```
df['date'] = [str(x) for x in df['date']]
df['date'] = df['date'].str.split('.').str[0]
```

and then using the operation at the top, and then using `strptime` to convert to a datetime object.

Comment: Can you post an example which produces the IndexError?

Comment: @unutbu you mean full code or an example date or...? The line of code I have there is giving me the index error.

Comment: If your DataFrame were something simple like `df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['20000101', '20000102']})`, then the line you posted would not raise an `IndexError`. There are plenty of ways to solve your problem when the DataFrame is simple like the example above, but they may not work for you unless we can identify why you are getting the IndexError. Some value in that column may not be a simple string of the form `YYYYMMDD`...

Comment: Ah, I can reproduce the error if `df = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.array([20000101, 20000102])})`.

Comment: Looks like the problem is the excel sheet the data is grabbed from has it formatted as number, so `pandas` is reading it in as `numpy.float64` instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you are getting the IndexError because the `date` column has dtype `float64`:

```
In [138]: df = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.array([20000101, 20000102])})

In [139]: df['date'] = [(x[:4] + '-' + x[4:6] + '-' + x[6]) for x in df['date']]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-139-f88e4248d599> in <module>()
----> 1 df['date'] = [(x[:4] + '-' + x[4:6] + '-' + x[6]) for x in df['date']]

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

---

One way to address the problem would be to convert the floats to strings, and then convert the strings to pandas.Timestamps:

```
In [136]: df['date'].astype('|S8').map(pd.Timestamp)
Out[136]: 
0   2000-01-01
1   2000-01-02
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: This works to get timestamps, but I'm working with datatime. Figured that out, editing my original post with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('20140101', '%Y%m%d')
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> date = datetime.strptime('20140101', '%Y%m%d')
>>> date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2014-01-01'
>>>
```

Comment: That gives me a `TypeError: buzzer size mismatch`, tried it earlier.

Comment: Er, when I use `time.strptime`, I get that error. Using `datatime.strptime` I get `TypeError: must be string, not numpy.float64`, which I guess means I may have to change that into a string, and that would explain my problem.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the problem.